# Write form info into array and display it

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

this is my code , actually i have a html form when i insert the name and phone of someone , i need that when i send a new contact in the form , it writes it on a array , and prints it on the h4 label , actually i only could make this with only one contact , when i send another , the first dissapear , but i couldnt make an array which gets written with the new info and later it displays all the info.
How i could do for my info gets written on the array and displayed later?
I know its easier with a database but i cant use that option.
Thanks all :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario2</title>
        <style>
            .myDiv {
              border: 5px outset white;
              background-color: #f1616e;
              text-align: center;
              width: 450px;
              height: 150px;
              margin: auto;
            }
            .myDiv2 {
              border: 5px outset white;
              background-color: #f1616e;
              text-align: center;
              width: 450px;
              height: 50px;
              margin: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#f1616e;">
        <?php
//======================================================================
// PROCESAR FORMULARIO
//======================================================================
// Comprobamos se chegan os datos por POST
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//======================================================================
                $erros = [];
                $nome = isset($_REQUEST['nombre']) ? $_REQUEST['nombre'] : null;
                $telefono = isset($_REQUEST['telefono']) ? $_REQUEST['telefono'] : null;
                
//====================================================================== 
                
                //Verifica los campos y actua
                    if(empty ($nome)){
                        echo "Nome baleiro";
                    }elseif(empty ($telefono)){
                        
                        echo "Contacto borrado"; 
                    }
            }
            

        ?>

        <h3 align="center" style="color:#2d5df3">Axenda</h3>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="myDiv" align="center">
                <br>
                Nome: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
                Telefono: <input type="tel" name="telefono" pattern="[0-9]{9}"><br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Engadir contacto"><input type="reset" name="Limpar Campos"><br>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h4 align="center">Datos axenda</h4>
        <div align="center" class="myDiv">
        <?php
                    echo $telefono." de ".$nome."\n";

        ?>
        </div>
        
        <div align="center" class="myDiv2">
            <input type="button" name="vaciaaxenda" value="Vaciar axenda">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saving it into an array is the easy part, saving it for later is the hard part. You can't store it in memory, because only that user will have access to it, and only for a short time. Same goes for a cookie, though for a longer time. Your best bet is to save it to a file, save it to a database, or email it to the person who needs it.

Comment: But i need saving it to a array :(

Comment: An array is just a data structure, and actually is already an array when the form is submitted, in `$_POST`. But that array doesn't stay anywhere until you store it

Comment: You could save to a json text file. Convert your array to json. Then when you read the file in decode the json back into an array. Edit the array as needed then encode to json and write the file. Just make sure the file is out side the web server directory.

Comment: I only could use arrays , i cant use other methods like another files or databases

Comment: Are you suppose to be using cookies or sessions? Other wise that makes no sense.

Comment: Using sessions at this time

Comment: None of your code references sessions. Look at this to get started. https://linuxhint.com/php-session-tutorial/